# Python multiprocessing.Processgetting generates AssertionError when attempting to get results returned?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I am trying to use `multiprocessing` for a task that is very slow when done as a single process. As you can see in the code below, each process is supposed to return some results (`return_dict`). I initially tested this code with a 10K row dataset (the data stored in the `docs.txt` file, about 70mb), and the code ran as expected. However, when I used the script for the full data set (approx. 5.6gb), I got an `AssertionError` as shown at the bottom of my question. I wonder if anyone knows what may have caused it and how I may be able to avoid it. Thanks.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
import os, io, numpy
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec

def worker(i, data, return_dict):
    model = Doc2Vec.load("D:\\Project1\\doc2vec_model_DM_20180814.model")
    results = numpy.zeros((len(data), model.vector_size))
    for id, doc in enumerate(data):
        results[id,:] = model.infer_vector(doc, alpha = 0.01, steps = 100)
    return_dict[i] = results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time
    a  = time.time()
    path = "D:\\Project1\\docs.txt"    # <<=== data stored in this file
    data = []
    manager = Manager()
    jobs = []
    return_dict = manager.dict()

    with io.open(path, "r+", encoding = "utf-8") as datafile:
        for id, row in enumerate(datafile):
            row = row.strip().split('\t')[0].split()
            data.append(row)

    step = numpy.floor(len(data)/20)
    intervals = numpy.arange(0, len(data), step = int(step)).tolist()
    intervals.append(len(data))

    for i in range(len(intervals) - 1):
        p = Process(target=worker, args=(i, data[intervals[i]:intervals[i+1]], return_dict))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
    for proc in jobs:
        proc.join()

    results = numpy.zeros((len(data), 1000))
    start = 0
    end = 0
    for _, result in return_dict.items():    #<<===Where error happens
        end = end + result.shape[0]
        results[start:end,:] = result[:,:]
        start = end

    print(time.time() - a)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Project1\multiprocessing_test.py", line 43, in <module>
    for _, result in return_dict.items():
  File "<string>", line 2, in items
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 757, in _callmethod
    kind, result = conn.recv()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 250, in recv
    buf = self._recv_bytes()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 318, in _recv_bytes
    return self._get_more_data(ov, maxsize)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 337, in _get_more_data
    assert left > 0
AssertionError
```

Comment: How about your memory usage during the whole process? The memory usage should  between `2*5.6gb` and `3*5.6gb` including virtual memory.

Comment: memory might be an issue? The result_dict contains 20 elements, each element is a numpy array in the size of approximately 425k row and 1000 columns of float values. My computer has 256 GB ram, during the actual multiprocessing phrase, the computer had 50% of the ram free. I was at my computer when the error happened, so I don’t know what the memory usage was like then.

Comment: Well, as you have such large ram, I guess it won't be a memory issue. Basically, it looks like an issue that your child processes don't really transport the whole data to your main process. It's weired as I think `return_dict[i] = results` should be a blocking operation. I cannot debug your code so I cannot figure out the root cause. An alternative solution can be using `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` as it allows you to get the return value of target function: `future = executor.submit(args)` & `result = future.result()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python multiprocessing apply\_async "assert left > 0" AssertionError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47692566/python-multiprocessing-apply-async-assert-left-0-assertionerror)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using all your available memory.
`dict.items()` creates a copy of your dict filled with all your items and using a lot of memory. Better just use `dict.iteritems()` to iterate over your result.

Edit: Sorry, I didn't notice the python-3 tag at first. In Python3, `dict.items()`doesn't return a copy anymore and should be ok to use.

The relevant code of connection.py in multiprocessing is

```
left = _winapi.PeekNamedPipe(self._handle)[1]
assert left > 0
```

Are you using windows? So I guess it is some windows related problem, it seems that PeekNamedPipe returns 0.

Comment: Yes you can just use items(). Python 3 items() ist Python 2 iteritems().

Answer (score 0):

This is my case and solution.Hope this can help!
I have a function to process named as "func"

```
partial_func = partial(func,a=params1,b=params2)
for i, _ in enumerate(pool.imap(partial_func, [1]))):
    pass
```

the root cause is the params1 and params2 that i pass to the "**partial_func**" is too large.